# Single jQuery to update multiple elements

Tags: php, jquery

I have the following jquery statement:

```
$("#add").click(
  function(event){
    var groupName = $("#groupName option:selected").text();
    var studentsToAdd = $('select#mainList').val();
    var mode = "exempt";
      $.post( 
         "addToList.php",
         { studentsToAdd: studentsToAdd, mode: mode },
         function(data) {
         $('#groupList').html(data[exemptList]);
         $('#mainList').html(data[nonexemptList]);
         }
      );
  });
```

With the following php code:

```
$studentsToAdd = $_REQUEST['studentsToAdd'];
$arrayLength = count($studentsToAdd);
$exemptList = "";
$nonexemptList = "";
for ($i=0;$i<$arrayLength;$i++){
    $result = mysql_query("UPDATE students SET exempt=1 WHERE id = '$studentsToAdd[$i]'");
    }
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from students WHERE exempt = 1");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $exemptList = $exemptList . "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['last'] . ", " . $row['first'] . "</option>";
}
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from students WHERE exempt = 0");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $nonexemptList = $nonexemptList . "<option value=\"" . $row['id'] . "\">" . $row['last'] . ", " . $row['first'] . "</option>";
}
$data = array(
    'exemptList' => $exemptList,
    'nonexemptList' => $nonexemptList
    );
echo json_encode($data);
```

I am trying to update both mainList and exemptList select elements with the single jQuery .post. It is not working. Thoughts?

Comment: in your javascript, `exemptList` and `nonexemptList` are undefined. You likely meant for those to be strings. you should also set the proper contentType in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your php code is in another page or in a function, which you haven't mentioned, `return $data` instead of `return json_encode($data)` should work and leave it as an array. Otherwise you are getting a json string back, from `json_encode()`, which you need to parse into a javascript object, so try:

```
var decoded = $.parseJSON(data);
$('#groupList').html(decoded.exemptList);
$('#mainList').html(decoded.nonexemptList);
```

At least from what i can tell at first glance and 11 pm.

Edit: You can always try `console.log(data)` with Firefox Firebug plugin and see what you are getting from the server and then see if you need to decode what you are getting, change how you write the array or quotes or whatever.

Comment: Thank you so much for that. I changed to bits of code to make it work based on your solution.  `$.post( 
             "addToList.php",
             { studentsToAdd: studentsToAdd, mode: mode },
             function(data) {
    $('#groupList').html(data.exemptList);
    $('#mainList').html(data.nonexemptList);
             },"json"
        );`   And   `echo json_encode(array(
  'exemptList' => $exemptList,
  'nonexemptList' => $nonexemptList
  ));`code`

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution is to decode the JSON object when it is returned.  Additionally, the stuff inside the [] needs to have quotes around it:

```
function(data) {
    var json = JSON.parse(data);

    $('#groupList').html(json["exemptList"]);
    $('#mainList').html(json["nonexemptList"]);
}
```

Also, maybe try $.ajax, and set *dataType* to json (even though the default is *intelligent guess*, which should work anyway since the PHP is sending a JSON object.)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try:

```
function(data) {
    $('#groupList').html(data["exemptList"]);
    $('#mainList').html(data["nonexemptList"]);
}
```

`exemptList` and `nonexemptList` were probably treated as variables instead of names.